# SSRS #ERROR Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am getting an #ERROR in SSRS. I believe it's happening when it tries to divide 0 by 0.

How can I change this to handle that scenario.

```
=Fields!Total_Incidents.Value/Fields!Units_Sold.Value
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS hide #Error displayed in cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144312/ssrs-hide-error-displayed-in-cell)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function in custom code of the report, ex:

```
function divide(a as decimal, b as decimal) as decimal
   if (b > 0.0) then
      divide = a/b
   else
      divide = 0
   end if
end function
```

Then, call this function in your textbox expression

Comment: it should be `b <> 0`

Comment: That seems a little confusing and sure what your variables a and b are suppose to represent. I just need to know how to do this =Fields!Total_Incidents.Value/Fields!Units_Sold.Value and not have it error. The problem is the Fields!Units_Sold.Value has values of 0 that I need to account for somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I ended up doing it

```
=IIf(Fields!Units_Sold.Value = 0, 0, Fields!Total_Incidents.Value / IIf(Fields!Units_Sold.Value = 0, 1, Fields!Units_Sold.Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check denominator is zero or not,
=IFF(Fields!Units_Sold.Value=0,0,Fields!Total_Incidents.Value/Fields!Units_Sold.Value)